# SCCM .cmd script will not work properly

Tags: java, sccm

I have googled this like crazy, so if this has been posted before, apologies.

I usually push updates via SCCM with .cmd scripts, so I can uninstall the previous version, and install the new version fresh.

code:

```
@echo off

REM Kill IE & Java Processes
cls
echo --------------------------------------------------------
echo       This will kill Browsers and Java Processes
echo --------------------------------------------------------
taskkill /F /IM iexplorer.exe
taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe
taskkill /F /IM firefox.exe
taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe
taskkill /F /IM jusched.exe
taskkill /F /IM jp2launcher.exe
taskkill /F /IM java.exe
taskkill /F /IM javaw.exe
taskkill /F /IM jqs.exe

REM Uninstalling Old JRE Versions
cls
echo --------------------------------------------------------
echo.              DO NOT CLOSE THIS WINDOW
echo. All the Java versions from your computer are being removed.
echo --------------------------------------------------------
wmic product where "name like 'J2SE%%'" call uninstall
wmic product where "name like 'Java 2%%'" call uninstall
wmic product where "name like 'Java 3%%'" call uninstall
wmic product where "name like 'Java 4%%'" call uninstall
wmic product where "name like 'Java 5%%'" call uninstall
wmic product where "name like 'Java(TM) 6%%'" call uninstall
wmic product where "name like 'Java 7%%'" call uninstall
wmic product where "name like 'Java 8%%'" call uninstall

REM Installing Java 1.8u77
cls
echo --------------------------------------------------------
echo .
echo .
echo .      Installing Java Runtime Environment - Please Wait.
echo .         (This window will close once installed)
echo .

mkdir c:\programdata\oracle\java
mkdir "c:\windows\sun\java\deployment"
copy  java.settings.cfg c:\programdata\Oracle\Java\java.settings.cfg   >>c:\programdata\oracle\java\copylog.log

REM Installing JRE 32-bit
"%~dp0jre-8u77-windows-i586.exe" INSTALL_SILENT=1 STATIC=0 AUTO_UPDATE=0 WEB_JAVA=1 WEB_ANALYTICS=0 EULA=0 REBOOT=0

REM If 64-bit Windows JRE 64-bit is also required
REM Installing JRE 64-bit
if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\" "%~dp0jre-8u77-windows-x64.exe" INSTALL_SILENT=1 STATIC=0 AUTO_UPDATE=0 WEB_JAVA=1 WEB_ANALYTICS=0 EULA=0 REBOOT=0

REM Disable automatic updates
reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v SunJavaUpdateSched /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy" /v EnableJavaUpdate /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

copy deployment.config c:\windows\sun\java\deployment\deployment.config   >>c:\programdata\oracle\java\copylog.log
copy deployment.properties c:\windows\sun\java\deployment\deployment.properties   >>c:\programdata\oracle\java\copylog.log
copy exception.sites c:\windows\sun\java\deployment\exception.sites   >>c:\programdata\oracle\java\copylog.log

REM Return exit code to SCCM
exit /B %EXIT_CODE%
```

For some reason, it only ever installs the 64 bit version, never both. I have done this as a Package and Application, same result. I've removed the "if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\"" portion, nothing. I've created separate deployments and called the 32 bit first, nothing.

I'm kind lost as to why its only installing the 64-bit version.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: And yes, I have tested it locally, the script works great when not deployed via SCCM

EDIT: I am attempting to deploy this script to Windows 8.1 and 7 machines, from a SCCM 2012 R2 server. I have deployed with this format before, and as experience dictates, sometimes things get bent out of shape with new programs.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just tossing out this version. I used the exact same script with 1.8u73, and it worked just fine. I think there is something wrong with the 32-bit executable for 77.

And seeing as 73 is stable and pings fine on my Nessus scans, I'll be going with that for now.

Answer (score 0):

Gareth,

After looking at your script and a number of others, I managed to amalgamate a working mess that will install both 32 and 64 bit Java 8u77 Runtimes.  Right now I know its will install to a collection but I'm just starting to test the install with OSD.

1) Download both 32 and 64 bit exe files from Oracle and copy to your repository.

2) Open the 32 bit .exe

3) Copy the jre1.8.0_77.msi file from C:\Users\\AppData\Oracle\Java\jre1.8.0_77 folder to your repository.

4) Create your java.settings.cfg file in the repository

```
INSTALL_SILENT=Enable
STATIC=Disable
AUTO_UPDATE=Disable
WEB_JAVA=Enable
WEB_JAVA_SECURITY_LEVEL=H
WEB_ANALYTICS=Disable
EULA=Disable
REBOOT=Disable
NOSTARTMENU=Disable
SPONSORS=Disable
```

** Yes I know not all these work but I still put them in anyway...

5) Create your install.cmd file:

```
@echo off

REM *** Copy the files needed for install to the appropriate locations
    IF NOT EXIST "%allusersprofile%\Oracle\Java" md "%allusersprofile%\Oracle\Java"
    copy /y "%~dp0java.settings.cfg" "%allusersprofile%\Oracle\Java"

    IF NOT EXIST "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\LocalLow\Oracle\Java\jre1.8.0_77" md "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\LocalLow\Oracle\Java\jre1.8.0_77"
    copy /y "%~dp0jre1.8.0_77.msi" "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\LocalLow\Oracle\Java\jre1.8.0_77"

REM *** Start our main x86 installer. Change your options here.
    start /w "x" jre-8u77-windows-i586.exe /s SPONSORS=Disable INSTALLCFG=%~dp0java.settings.cfg REBOOT=ReallySuppress /L*V "C:\Windows\CCM\SoftwareLogs\JRE8u77Install.txt"
REM *** Start our main x64 installer. Change your options here.
    if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\" start /w "x" jre-8u77-windows-x64.exe /s SPONSORS=Disable INSTALLCFG=%~dp0java.settings.cfg REBOOT=ReallySuppress /L*V "C:\Windows\CCM\SoftwareLogs\JRE8u77x64Install.txt"

REM *** Exit the script back to SCCM.
exit /B %EXIT_CODE%
```

6) Optional: Create an uninstall.cmd

```
@Echo OFf
REM Java Runtime 8 Uninstallers for x86 and x64 Update 77
msiexec /x {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218077F0} /q
msiexec /x {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418077F0} /q
```

7) Create the Application in SCCM and use the install and uninstall scripts.  For install detection I just used the WMI codes from the Uninstall script.

Deploy to your collection and voila, you should have a full operational JRE installation with both the 32 & 64 bit installers.

I'm not sure if I should remove the "copied" files once the install is completed but I'm sure other will chime in and let us know, and its easy enough to modify.

Hope this helps.
DC